# Can't interact with a file with an apostraphe directly in bash

Tags: bash, files

I have a file titled "I'm Here.mp3" when I try to interact with it with ls, cp, mv, anything, it returns `cannot stat "./I'm Here.mp3": No such file or directory`.

I tried double quotes, single quotes, no quotes, each with and without trying to escape the apostraphe with a backslash, i checked the permissions, i created a dummy file with touch called "I'm Here.png" and that has no problem, and I have no problem with the other files in the same folder, just this single file that happens to have an apostraphe.

What would make a file like this not be recognised in the terminal? I can still listen to it through media players, copy, paste, and move in a file manager, etc, but I'm trying to correct the metadata of a folder of files like this.

With the command `ls | hexdump -C` I can identify the apostrophe as the hexadecimal values `e2 80 99`.

Comment: This is a helpful little tool: https://www.cogsci.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi. Select the `Hex UTF-8 bytes` button, type your `e2 80 99` at the top, hit `Go`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If quoting the filename `I'm here.mp3` doesn't work in any way, then probably the filename is actually not what it looks.

Maybe the space between `I'm` and `Here` is not a space, or there is an additional space (or other invisible character) at the end of the name, after `mp3`. Do `ls | hexdump -C` to view the file names in the directory in hexadecimal, then use the proper character in filename according to the hexadecimal output you get.

Comment: me too usually but this is different, it just returns the same `mv I\'m\ Here.mp3 ./test.mp3
mv: cannot stat "I'm Here.mp3": No such file or directory
`

Comment: thank you! the apostraphe isn't what it seemed lol the problem hex was `e2 80 99` could you point me to a reference of what hex is what characters? i'd like to know what to call it other than e2 80 99 haha

Comment: The character is (based on your own comment) a [RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm), which, encoded in UTF-8, is `e2 80 99`.

Comment: As it stands right now, the answer, although accepted, does not answer the question, nor does it explain the issue.

Comment: @Kusalananda I have edited the answer to actually explain the issue.